# Best choice to store a list of ints in mssql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, list

I am wondering which method is the best way to store a list of integers in a sql column.
.....i.e. "1,2,3,4,6,7"

EDIT: These values represent other IDs in SQL tables. The row would look like

> [1] [2]
>
> id, listOfOtherIDs

The choices I have researched so far are:

1. A varchar of separated value that are "explode-able" i.e. by commas or tabs
2. An XML containing all the values individually
3. Using individual rows for each value.

Which method is the best method to use?

Thanks,
Ian

Comment: You should update your question and explain what exactly this list of ints represents. Most likely, it will become obvious that (like Jeroen said) you're doing it wrong, and that list should be a number of entries in another table.

Comment: Regarding your edit: you'll want to use my answer. ID's that link to a different table should be used as Foreign Keys, you can't do that if they're all grouped in one field.

Answer (score 8):

A single element of a record can only refer to one value; it's a basic database design principle.

You will have to change the database's design: use a single row for each value.
You might want to read up on [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

As is shown [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/database-design-basics-HA010341617.aspx) in the description of the *first normal form*:

> First normal form states that at every row and column intersection in the table there, exists a single value, and never a list of values. For example, you cannot have a field named Price in which you place more than one Price. If you think of each intersection of rows and columns as a cell, each cell can hold only one value.

Answer (score 4):

While Jeroen's answer is valid for "multi-valued" attributes, there are genuine situations where multiple comma-separated values may actually be representing one large value. Things like path data (on a map), integer sequence, list of prime factors and many more could well be stored in a comma-separated varchar. I think it is better to explain what exactly are you storing and how do you need to retrieve and use that value.

**EDIT:**

Looking at your edit, if by IDs you mean PK of another table, then this sounds like a genuine M-N relation between this table and the one whose IDs you're storing. This stuff should really be stored in a separate gerund, which BTW is a table that would have the PK of each of these tables as FKs, thus linking the related rows of both tables. So Jeroen's answer very well suits your situation.

Comment: +1, good point. I looked past that option since he suggested himself to put the values in different records.

Comment: Thanks. I see. But some would even insist on storing list of prime factors in multiple rows. ;-)